# How do I reload TMUX configuration?

Tags: tmux

Trying to transition to tmux (version 1.6) on OS X 10.7 (so I'm sure I am making a noob mistake) and having problems with the simplest of commands. In my ~/.tmux.conf I have to map the prefix to Ctrl-a rather than :

```
set -g prefix C-a
```

but when I:

```
Wed Apr 10$ source ~/.tmux.conf                                                       │                                                                                      
-bash: set: -g: invalid option                                                        │                                                                                      
set: usage: set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option] [arg ...]                           │                                                                                      
Wed Apr 10$
```

I get the invalid option error. Is this just a syntax issue or might there be some other conifguration issue? How would I fix this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`tmux.conf` is the configuration file **for tmux**. You are not supposed to source it within your *shell*, but rather tell tmux to source it.

Any of the following should work:

- run **`tmux source ~/.tmux.conf`**
- run `tmux set -g prefix C-a`
- press the old prefix (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>), `:source ~/.tmux.conf`
- press the old prefix (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>), `:set -g prefix C-a`