# Even though I have enabled scrolling through mouse - setw -g mouse on, mouse scrolling is not working in tmux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, tmux

I have the below configuration in my ~/.tmux.conf

```
  1 unbind -a
  2 
  3 set -g prefix C-a
  4 unbind C-b
  5 bind C-a send-prefix
  6 
  7 set-option -g status-left-length 100
  8 setw -g mouse on
  9 
 10 # 0 is too far from ` ;)
 11 set -g base-index 1
 12 setw -g pane-base-index 1
 13 
 14 # Automatically set window title
 15 set-window-option -g automatic-rename on
 16 set-option -g set-titles on
 17 
 18 # Use Ctrl key to manage windows
 19 bind-key -n C-n new-window
 20 
 21 # Use Alt-arrow keys without prefix key to switch panes
 22 bind -n S-Left select-pane -L
 23 bind -n S-Right select-pane -R
 24 bind -n S-Up select-pane -U
 25 bind -n S-Down select-pane -D
 26 
 27 bind -n C-i split-window -h 
 28 bind -n C-h split-window -v
 29 
 30 # Use Ctrl-arrow to switch windows
 31 bind -n C-Left  previous-window
 32 bind -n C-Right next-window
 33 
 34 set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
 35 
 36 set-option -g history-limit 10000
 37 
 38 # Reload tmux config
 39 #bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf
 40
```

Even though I have enabled scrolling through mouse - `setw -g mouse on`, mouse scrolling is not working in tmux

What could be the issue?

Comment: Get rid of `set-option -g status-left-length 100`

Comment: That I added because my session name was getting truncated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the tmux server had got messed up.
Killing all the tmux session and inturn the tmux server.
And creating a new session afterwards, I am able to use the mouse scroller to scroll through the terminal.

Comment: Can it be you didn't [reload the file](https://superuser.com/a/580999/432690)? Restarting the server loaded the file anew.

Comment: I am sure, I've sourced the ~/.tmux.conf file. In fact multiple times, since I was tweaking with some key binding